# Can I get a Vertex instead of an Element out of this GraphTraversal?

Tags: java, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am using [Tinkerpop3 Gremlin](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/) against the reference TinkerGraph implementation.

I am attempting to `.next()` a `Vertex` out this Traversal:

```
graph.V().has(T.label, "link").has("url", url).next();
```

Unfortunately, I am only able to get an `Element` from `next()`. When I assign the output of `next()` into a `Vertex`, I get:

> error: incompatible types: Element cannot be converted to Vertex

**How can I get a `Vertex`**?

I've looked at [the docs](http://www.tinkerpop.com/javadocs/3.0.0.M6/full/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/graph/GraphTraversal.html) and see that `V()` returns `GraphTraversal<Vertex,Vertex>`. The `has()` steps are signed `default <E2 extends Element> GraphTraversal<S,E2>`, which I thought would preserve the `GraphTraveral<Vertex, Vertex>` but `next()` yields only `Element`. Not sure what to do next.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - you could always do this:

```
Vertex v = g.V().has(T.label, "link").<Vertex>has("name", url).next();
```

and simply explicitly type the last step.

Comment: Even though the above works, I didn't think it was necessary to do that - will check into it further.

Comment: Stephen, thanks, I found a similar version of this that works. New to Java which must be part of why this stumped me so. But still, I don't get why the compiler needed that extra bit. If you take apart the chain and assign each step to a variable it's `Vertex` all the way. No idea why `Element` is introduced by the compiler.